# Real world raffle occurrence - this really happened!

Tags: probability-theory

A friend of mine and I joined a raffle the other week. There were about 80 participants and 40 prizes, which were actually items donated by 40 of the participants.

Just over 200 tickets were sold (let's assume 240).

The prizes were given away to holders of winning numbers in random order by someone who had no idea who had brought which prize (and winning numbers were discarded).

My friend bought 2 tickets and won once. He was handed the prize he had donated!

I had bought 4 tickets and won once. I was also handed the item that I had donated as a prize..!

In addition, there were 10 tables of 8 and my friend I were sitting side by side. No one else won the same item they had donated.

After a lot of laughter, we started wondering the odds of what just happened but couldn't manage. Can someone help please us?

Cheers!

Comment: Comment since not an answer (someone else will provide the numbers). In situations like this you can always look at the results after the fact and find some things that look like strange coincidences. But that's often because there are lots of possible things you would think of as strangely coincidental, and _some_ of them will happen. It's only after the fact that you know which ones. In your case, with $40$ prizes and $80$ people it's quite likely that many will get the prize they donated, and then that some of those people will be friends or tablemates.

Comment: Thank you Ethan! I see your point, but this is how I thought: Suppose everyone bought the same no of raffle tickets. Then everyone had a 1/2 chance of winning a prize. And then there's a 1/40 chance of being handed back their own donation. That's already odds of 1/80 for a single person, I thought. Am I mistaken? And then this to happen to 2 different people - I think - not less than 1/3200.. I'm pretty sure I'm making a mistake somewhere so I'm happy to be corrected!

Comment: Similar to the [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Is it really? Hmm

Answer (score 0):

Very rough calculation for part of the question.

For each of the $40$ people the probability that they get their contribution as a prize is $1/80$. The probability that they don't is thus $79/80$. So the probability that no one gets what he or she brought is 
$$
\left( \frac{79}{80} \right) ^ {40} \approx 0.60
$$
so about $60\%$.

Comment: Hi Ethan thank you for taking the time. Yes sure 40% that someone gets his/her own contribution is a big probability. But this happening to 2 people in this instance who happened to be sitting next to each other (another 1/40) would be a much smaller probability I guess..

Comment: @yucina $40\%$ isn't 1/40, it.s $2/5$. That's the chance that at least one person gets his or her contribution back.  I think the chance that at least two people do  is about $20\%$. Then you can look for all kinds of coincidences - sitting together, knowing each other, having the same first name, having contributed the same item. When you see one such you'll say "that's strange" - but it's not. Among the possible coincidences a few will happen even though any particular one is unlikely, After all, someone wins powerball.

Comment: Dear Ethan, it's very sweet of you to try and correct me thinking that I would believe 40% to be 1/40. God bless. When I wrote "another 1/40", I was of course referring to the probability of these two people sitting next to to each other (if they sat at one big table). With the group sitting around a number of smaller tables, it is actually less than that.

Comment: Anyway, as no one has come forward to actually solve the question, I asked a friend of mine who's a bit of a mathematician and have posted the answer. Perhaps surprisingly for you Ethan, the solution yields a very low probability. Would be absolutely delighted to hear back from you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler calculation we'll assume that everyone bought 3 tickets each.

Probability of having exactly one winning ticket out of 3 is

40/240 * 200/239 * 200/238  +  200/240 * 39/239 * 200/238  +  200/240 * 200/239 * 38/238

which is approximately 49.4% Probability that this is the item you brought is 1/40. So probability of winning exactly the same item you brought is

49.4/40 = 0.12341338

approximately 12 out of 10.000

Probability that 2 specific people winning the same item they brought is

C(80,2) p^2 (1-p)^78 = (80*79)/(2*1) * 0.0012341338^2 * (1.0 - 0.0012341338)^78

which is 6.81488535036258 E-21 which is practically 0.

In this case, we will not even calculate for the probability of the 2 sitting side by side.